# Audio controls на экране блокировки

Tags: ios

У меня есть iOS приложение, которое воспроизводит аудиофайлы с сервера.

Если во время воспроизведения заблокировать экран, то на экране блокировки появляется стандартная область с аудиоконтролами. Эта же область есть и в нижней шторке (см. скрины).
Как моему приложению нужно взаимодействовать с ней? Мне необходимо  реализовать как минимум два действия: play и stop.
Как называется эта область с аудиоконтролами на экране блокировки? Где искать информацию по работе с ней?

[image: Скрин экрана блокировки]

[image: Скрин нижней шторки]

Comment: `MPRemoteCommandCenter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого испольуется синглтон `MPRemoteCommandCenter`

Например, вы можете задать, что должно сделать ваше приложение, когда пользователь нажимает play:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.enabled = YES;

//playCommandTarget это переменная, в которой вы сохраняете handler, чтобы можно было его потом убрать
self.playCommandTarget = [remoteCommandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *_Nonnull event) {
    [self.player play]; // или как у вас там делается play
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess; // тут надо проверить запустилось ли воспроизведение на самом деле и вернуть соответствующий код
}];
```

Убрать handler когда он не нужен

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[remoteCommandCenter.playCommand removeTarget:self.playCommandTarget];
```